# Adding a text from one file when finding a match on another file

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I search through many answers and could not find anything on it.

I have a text file (from an exam) and the answers are in another file.
I managed to add the text "Answer: " at the end of each question, but now I cannot find a way to pick up the answer from file2 into the file1.

file1:

Question: 179 – Alterando-se o ângulo de ataque de 0º para 6º, a resistência parasita:

```
a Aumenta 
b) Não se altera 
c) Diminui 
d) Impossível de se determinar 
Answer:
```

file2:

```
177)C
178)A
179)B
180)B
```

I tried to use sed but so far no success, any suggestion would be appreciated.

The file1 structure repeats for every question, but sometimes Questions can have more than one line.

The desired output should be:

Question: 179 – Alterando-se o ângulo de ataque de 0º para 6º, a resistência parasita:

```
a Aumenta 
b) Não se altera 
c) Diminui 
d) Impossível de se determinar 
Answer: B
```

Comment: there is always 4 answer and file 1 have the same structure of 1 line for the question 1 blank line 4 lines of reply, 1 blank line than next question ? Also give an expected output, that help to format and understand

Comment: I edit the original text to include the answers you need. Thanks for your interest in my question.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` would hardly be my tool of choice for this, whereas it is reasonably easy in Awk.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
        # NR is equal to FNR when we are reading the first input file
        # Store the right answer for each question in an array
        split($1, b, /\)/)
        # If the input was 123)A, the array b now contains "123" and "A"
        a[b[1]] = b[2]
        # We are done; skip to next line
        next
    }
    # If we are here, we are in the second file.  Find a question delimiter
    /Question: [0-9]+/ {
        # If we have the previous question in memory, print its answer first
        if (q>0) { print "\nAnswer: " a[q] "\n\n" }
        # Remember index for this question
        q=$2
    }
    # If we are this far, perform the default action, that is, print this line
    # "1" is a shorthand for "print the current line"
    1
    # At the end of the file, print the last remaining answer
    END { print "\nAnswer: " a[q] "\n\n" }' file2 file1
```

This isn't entirely robust if the format of the question header or the data in the answers file isn't completely regular, though.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer tripleee, but I did not manage to make this work. I put your solution inside a bash script file, and tried to run it followed by the files names but it just locks the console. I have to press Ctrl+C to get it back. (I did allow it more that 15 min before doing so...)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and sorry for the sloppy copy/paste.  I fixed a couple of issues and confirmed that it works for me now.  Apologies for the incomplete answer before.

Comment: The script indeed work this time, but for some questions the output was not as expected.
I will add an example of the output

Comment: Well, there are a couple of caveats in the answer.  If you can update your question with the corner cases, it will be easier to provide an answer which works for you.

Comment: Question: 179 – Alterando-se o ângulo de ataque de 0º para 6º, a resistência parasita:

a) Aumenta 
b) Não se altera 
c) Diminui 
d) Impossível de se determinar 
Answer:

Answer: B

Question: 180 – Considerando-se uma aeronave de 10.000 Kg de peso total e 100 m² de área de asa, a carga unitária será de:

Answer: B

a) Question: 0,01 m²/kg

Answer: 

b) Question: 100 kg/m²

Answer: 

c) Question: 1000 kg/m²

Answer: 


d)  Question: 0,01 kg/ m²
Answer:
 
Answer:

Comment: If you really need to have the string `Question:` in places where a new question does not begin, maybe change the regex to `/^Question: [0-9]+/` which will only match at beginning of line.  The example you posted looks like the question was just malformatted, though.

Comment: reply like we like +1